# html5 video playlist android

Tags: android, html, loops, video, autoplay

I'm currently working on a app with some native and html5 features.
The streamed content will be loaded in a webview.

I need a html5 videoplayer with a playlist, autoplay and autorepeat(loop).

I have it working on my chrome webbrowser. But for some reason it wont work in the webview on android.

```
<video id="awesome_video" width="100%" height="100%" src="video/video.mp4" autoplay />

        <script type="text/javascript">
          var index = 1,
              playlist = ["video/video.mp4", "video/video2.mp4"],
              video = document.getElementById('awesome_video');

          video.addEventListener('ended', rotate_video, false);

          function rotate_video() {
            video.setAttribute('src', playlist[index]);
            video.load();
            index++;
            if (index >= playlist.length) { index = 0; }
          }
        </script>
```

On android it wont start automatically, and when I touch the screen to play it takes some time to buffer. But after that no video is shown.

I know a repeat function that works on android:

```
video.addEventListener('ended', function() 
{ 
   video.currentTime=0.1;
   video.play(); 
}
```

In my android app i've already set my webview as chromeclient:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvMain);     
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

I can get it working without playlist and autoplay(just a single video played repeatedly).

Hope anyone knows how to get this working on an android device, thx.

Comment: are you enabling hardware acceleration for the WebView - seems to be needed to reliably get HTML5 video to play eg https://gist.github.com/Offbeatmammal/3718414

Comment: also IIRC autoplay is blocked in webviews (on Android and iOS) and you need to to manually trigger the play() from some other event